# Point within a triangle: barycentric co-ordinates

Tags: c++, geometry

I'm solving a classic problem of determining whether a point is within a triangle, and I'm using the barycentric co-ordinates method.
For some reason (I think it's the logic, not the precision) it doesn't pass all the tests.
What could be wrong?

The code is this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};


bool Place(point &A, point &B, point &C, point &P)
{

    double det = (B.y - C.y)*(A.x - C.x) + (C.x - B.x)*(A.y - C.y);
    double factor_alpha = (B.y - C.y)*(P.x - C.x) + (C.x - B.x)*(P.y - C.y);
    double factor_beta = (C.y - A.y)*(P.x - C.x) + (A.x - C.x)*(P.y - C.y);
    double alpha =  factor_alpha / det;
    double beta =  factor_beta / det;
    double gamma = 1.0 - alpha - beta;

    bool In = false;

    if (((A.x == P.x) & (A.y == P.y)) | ((B.x == P.x) & (B.y == P.y)) | ((C.x == P.x) & (C.y == P.y))) 
        In = true; // the sneaky guys are trying to see if the vertice of the triangle belongs to it
                    // the problem statement says it does.
    if ((alpha == 0) | (beta == 0) | (gamma == 0))
            In =  true; // the point is on the edge of the triangle
    if (( (0 < alpha) & (alpha < 1)) & ((0 < beta) & (beta < 1)) & ((0 < gamma) & (gamma < 1)))
            In =  true; // in this case P is actually within the triangle area

    return In;
}


int main()
{
    point A, B, C, P;
    cin >> A.x >> A.y >> B.x >> B.y >> C.x >> C.y >> P.x >> P.y;
    Place(A, B, C, P) ? cout << "In\n" : cout << "Out\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sarcasm alert, do not read on if you are faint of heart and spirit. Whatever you do don't tell us which tests it passes and which tests it fails.  Telling us would be too helpful.

Comment: I wouldn't know; I hoped the logic had an obvious flaw and thus and obvious correction existed.

Comment: It's passed to an online checking system. Life would be much easier if those gave their tests beforehand.

Comment: Roll up your sleeves and write some tests of your own.  As matters stand you are inviting SO to act as a sort of crowd-sourced replacement for the impenetrable online checking system; I don't think SOers will be queuing up for that. If you won't put any effort into testing your own code why should I or anyone else hereabouts ?

Comment: No (also, I wonder why it looks that way). I want SOers to have a look at the logic in function `Place`. The test can wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic says that the point is on the edge if at least one of `alpha`, `beta`, or `gamma` is 0.
That's necessary but not sufficient; the other ones must also be in the interval `[0, 1]`.

Since you're not interested in the "edge" case specifically, you could write

```
if (0 <= alpha && alpha <= 1 && 0 <= beta && beta <= 1 && 0 <= gamma && gamma <= 1)
        In = true;
```

(I removed some brackets and replaced the bitwise `&` with the logical `&&`.)

---

Readability suggestion:
Introducing a couple of functions makes the code look more like a mathematical definition:

```
bool operator ==(const point& a, const point& b)
{
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
}

bool within(double x)
{
    return 0 <= x && x <= 1;
}

bool Place(const point &A, const point &B, const point &C, const  point &P)
{   
    double det = (B.y - C.y)*(A.x - C.x) + (C.x - B.x)*(A.y - C.y);
    double factor_alpha = (B.y - C.y)*(P.x - C.x) + (C.x - B.x)*(P.y - C.y);
    double factor_beta = (C.y - A.y)*(P.x - C.x) + (A.x - C.x)*(P.y - C.y);
    double alpha = factor_alpha / det;
    double beta = factor_beta / det;
    double gamma = 1.0 - alpha - beta;

    return P == A || P == B || P == C || (within(alpha) && within(beta) && within(gamma));
}
```

Comment: Great, that might be it. On another point, why should I use logical `&&`? Wouldn't the lazy evalutaion mess with the desired logic?  UPD: miraculously, this worked.

Comment: @Chiffa No, the lazy evaluation preserves the logic. `false && x` is `false` regardless of the value of `x`.

Comment: All right, then. Also, the readibility improvements are great, I'll try to learn to write more like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function (assumes that you have a `Point` class template where `T` is the stored type, and also that you have overloaded `operator*` for computing the dot product):

```
template <typename T>
bool is_point_in_triangle(const Point<3,T>& p,
                          const Point<3,T>& a,
                          const Point<3,T>& b,
                          const Point<3,T>& c) {

  typedef Point<3,T> point_type;

  point_type v0 = b-a, v1 = c-a, v2 = p-a;

  T d00 = v0*v0;
  T d01 = v0*v1;
  T d11 = v1*v1;
  T d20 = v2*v0;
  T d21 = v2*v1;
  T denom = d00*d11 - d01*d01;

  // compute parametric coordinates
  Real v = (d11 * d20 - d01 * d21) / denom;
  Real w = (d00 * d21 - d01 * d20) / denom;  
  return v >= 0. && w >= 0. && v + w <= 1.;
}
```

As a side note, you're using `int` to store the coordinates, so your tests may be failing because of the truncation?
Good luck!

Comment: A template. Great. I should get back to this later when I'd be looking for other solutions to this problem. Also, my coordinates are guaranteed to satisfy -10000 <= x,y <= 10000, which should fit into an `int`

Comment: The problem is that you're also dividing by an `int`, so the result of `v` and `w` may be truncated if the division is not an integer.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks, I'll think about it.